# How do I channel all browsing traffic through encrypted sTunnel session?

Tags: unix, proxy, ssl-certificate, public-key-encryption, stunnel

I have `sTunnel` running on my client and server and can't seem to get my head round how I can have it running in a sort of "silent mode" whereby if I were abroad I could fire up the `sTunnel` connection on my client, connect to my server and then my browsing traffic connection would behave as if I were in the UK (an encrypted proxy).

**On the client conf I have:**

`accept = localhost:xxx` (I understand this means the local `sTunnel` installation listens on xxx port and grabs any traffic sent on that port).

`connect = serverip:xxx` (This is the instruction of where it needs to be forwarded, i.e the server).

**On my server:**

`accept: clientIP:xxx` (the source IP address of my client)
`connect: localhost:xxx` (the loopback address of the server)

What am I failing to see here? As I see it I can only use this tunnel if I explicitly target a port with my browser and even then wouldn't it only make it as far as the `sTunnel` server and not onward to the website intended? Do I need to setup proxy settings in the browser?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure [`stunnel`](http://ports.su/security/stunnel) is what you're looking for here.

What you describe would be best accomplished with [OpenSSH](http://BXR.SU/OpenBSD/usr.bin/ssh/), and its ***dynamic SOCKS5 proxy*** functionality, e.g. [`ssh -D1080`](http://mdoc.su/o/ssh.1) from the client.

This generally doesn't require any extra settings on the server-side (unless it was specifically disabled by your system administrator), and then on your roaming client-side, you simply establish an SSH connection to your server as per usual, but add an extra **`-D1080`** parameter to your [**`ssh`**](http://mdoc.su/o/ssh.1) invocation.

Or, if using **PuTTY**, set up dynamic port forwarding within <kbd>Connection</kbd>, <kbd>SSH</kbd>, <kbd>Tunnels</kbd>, <kbd>Source port</kbd> of <kbd>1080</kbd> and <kbd>Destination</kbd> of <kbd>Dynamic</kbd>, click <kbd>Add</kbd>.

Subsequently, change the settings of your browser to use SOCKS proxy at `localhost`, port `1080`, and also make sure to specify SOCKS v5 and ensure that the checkbox for resolving hostnames remotely is set, too.